# Regular Expression for Special Characters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, character-encoding, special-characters

I need the regex method in rails for the european language special characters like eg. é, ä, ö, ü, ß. Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you please be more concrete? You want to match all strings containing this characters? Or just the characters? What characters are considered _special_? Those not in english alphabet?

Comment: What are special characters?  Is `"‐"` or `"∕"` a special character? Are `"Α"` and `"В"`? How about `"$"`, `"¢"`, `"£"`, or `"€"`?  Heck, is `" "` a special character? Define *special character*.  Do you mean anything that isn’t included in [the standard character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50)?

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Be very careful about this "English alphabet" thing.  There is no such thing, you know.

Comment: I believe @alpha-mouse is referring to the letters commonly on an english keyboard, not trying to make an out-of-place political statement.

Comment: I knew what you meant, no worries :) In fact, you make a very good point.  Regular expressions do appear to be english centric.  For example, [a-zA-Z] in a regex will *not* match the common spanish letter "ñ".  I tried.  I'd be interested to hear from non-english regex users, on how they handle things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions will work just fine with "special" characters.  If you're wanting to *match* a set of special characters, you'll need to tell the expression exactly what those characters are.  Your definition of "special" might not match the next guy's.

For instance, if you wanted to see if a string contains any of the characters you listed above, you can do this:

```
irb(main):001:0> word = "resumé"
=> "resum\303\251"
irb(main):002:0> word =~ /[éäöüß]/
=> 5
irb(main):003:0> word.gsub(/é/, 'e')
=> "resume"
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this before and It showed the error "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)"... its not solved. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: I found the issue. The US-ASCII characters changed as UTF-8. Now its working with your script. Thanks lot!!!